# $\int \sin^{-1} {\sqrt {\frac {x} {x+1}}} {} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

solve with using integral by parts:$$\int \sin^{-1}  {\sqrt {\frac {x} {x+1}}} {} dx$$

I tried $u=\sin^{-1}  {\sqrt {\frac {x} {x+1}}}$ , $dv=dx$ but it cause more difficulty to solve

Comment: the quesstion said use integral by parts method

Comment: Hint: try $u=\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}$ and $dv=dx$.

Comment: You may notice that $\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}}=\arctan\sqrt{x}$. Through the substitution $x=z^2$ the problem boils down to the integration of $z\arctan(z)$, which is straighforward by integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks very good idea

Answer (score 0):

Let $$u'=1,v=\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\right)$$ then
$$u=x,v'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{x+1}}}\times \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{-1/2}\times \frac{x+1-x}{(x+1)^2}dx$$